# How to get the individual paraformat values in a textimage component aem?

Tags: aem

I am using textimage component and added "paraformat" in rteplugins.
When I provide the values in the dialog, it gets saved as the property "text": `<h1>heading1</h1><h2>Heading2</h2><h3>Heading3</h3><p>Paragraph</p>`

Now, I want to get individual values eg. heading1, heading2 etc in this case.

I can apply some string functions. But, does anyone know any direct method to get these values?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with text component example hope the same helps (As it is not recommended to parse HTML with regex but for you to give some idea posting below answer)

**Created a component with rtePlugins as shown below**
[image: rtetextcomp]
**text.jsp code**

```
<%@page session="false"%>
<%@ page import="com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Placeholder,java.util.regex.Matcher,java.util.regex.Pattern" %>
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><cq:text property="text" escapeXml="true"
        placeholder="<%= Placeholder.getDefaultPlaceholder(slingRequest, component, null)%>"/>

<!-- Below code to demonstrate the Retrieval of paraformat -->
<%  String defaultMessage = properties.get("text", "");

    // the pattern we want to search for
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<p>(.*?)</p>");
    Pattern h1 = Pattern.compile("<h1>(.*?)</h1>");
    Pattern h2 = Pattern.compile("<h2>(.*?)</h2>");
    Pattern h3 = Pattern.compile("<h3>(.*?)</h3>");
    Matcher mp = p.matcher(defaultMessage);
    Matcher mh1 = h1.matcher(defaultMessage);
    Matcher mh2 = h2.matcher(defaultMessage);
    Matcher mh3 = h3.matcher(defaultMessage);

// if we find a match, get the group 
    if (mp.find()) {

      // get the matching group
          String parastring = mp.group(1);

      // print the group
        out.println("tag P : "+parastring +"</br>");
    }
 if (mh1.find()) {

      // get the matching group
          String h1string = mh1.group(1);

      // print the group
         out.println("tag h1 : "+h1string +"</br>");
    }
    if (mh2.find()) {
// get the matching group
          String h2string = mh2.group(1);

      // print the group
         out.println("tag h2 : "+h2string +"</br>");
    }
     if (mh3.find()) {

      // get the matching group
          String h3string = mh3.group(1);

      // print the group
         out.println("tag h3 : "+h3string +"</br>");
    }
      %>
```

**drag and drop the component in page and edit the rte** 
[image: rteedit]

Finally in page you can retrieve the text by using the `java.util.regex.*;` package as shown in the jsp code(which is not optimized just to give some understanding of how to satisfy the requirement you are looking for).
[image: tags code]